# Is there a Japanese input method for tablets that fits the screen better than Simeji?

Tags: tablet, languages, localization, input-methods

I do a fair amount of e-mailing in Japanese from GMail in Android. On my cell phone (Nexus One), I use [Simeji](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adamrocker.android.input.simeji) to type Japanese characters, and it does a good job. However, I recently got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 tablet, and I've found the Simeji doesn't scale well to the large screen.

Samsung's Android keyboard, the stock Android keyboard, and Hacker's Keyboard are all installed on my tablet, and all of them have a nice, large, easy-to-type-on display on the 10" screen. Simeji on the other hand, although functional, is displayed with keys sized more appropriately to a 4" screen, and is stretched awkwardly around the bottom 10-15% of the screen. At least this is true in landscape mode.

I'd like to have a Japanese input method for my tablet that makes better use of the screen real estate, and is easy to type on with two hands. Does anyone know of one? Or alternatively, is there some way I can change Simeji's configuration so it works better on a 10" screen?

**Update on August 20, 2011**

As of August 2011, I've noticed that Simeji has been updated to work well on a tablet now, so it's no longer necessary to have an alternative. Still, this question may benefit future searchers who just don't like Simeji for whatever reason and want an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second-hand answer - from here -  http://forum.koohii.com/viewtopic.php?id=8339

"Keyboard-wise, I like the MultiLing keyboard for my Xoom tablet. It's not particularly great as a keyboard, it's just that it scales nicely and fills the screen properly in Japanese mode, unlike any other keyboard for the tablet. It's sort of a Jack of All Trades, Master of None keyboard, in that it's adequate for Japanese, but it will drive you nuts. (But Simeji on a tablet is an even more horrible experience.)"

Answer (score 2):

Since I first asked this question, Google has released their own [Japanese Input method for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out Smart Keyboard. They have a Japanese add-on for their Keyboard. It scales nicely on my Asus Transformer and I use it to type Hiragana all the time for my Japanese class. It does katakana as well but I don't know how to write in that yet. The keyboard is setup so that if you type ku on your keyboard it will display く. This means you don't actually see their Hiragana characters. It still works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Swype is a great general use keyboard and has multi-lingual support.